# PHP site stopped serving on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

We have 2 websites on App Engine using PHP. These websites have been running perfectly until last night (UK time). All of a sudden they are not serving and are just coming up with a blank page.

App Engine is saying there are no issues and the instances are being logged - just the pages not showing.

There is nothing wrong with the App.Yaml file, nothing has changed. Does anyone know what the issues might be?

We are using a custom domain for one which is socialexposure.co.uk but this is not the issue as we cannot get to the app via the appengine id URL either.

Comment: `http://www.socialexposure.co.uk` works but `http://socialexposure.co.uk` responds with "Index of /" and no more in an html document.  DNS problems?

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be due to the changes to [SCRIPT_NAME and PHP_SELF](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2014/02/20/upcoming-changes-in-app-engine-1-9-0-for-script_name-and-php_self/) in the 1.9.0 release.